# Batch if statement not working in for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a hard time getting the if statement to work within the for 
loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
set filename=%%i
set filenametrunc=!filename:~0,28!
If %filename:~0,28%==ProjectLoad_Refresh_%today% (
Set fileName=%filenametrunc%
)
)
```

Comment: Keep referencing variables using `!` instead of `%` e.g. `!filename:~0,28!` and `!filenametrunc!` in scope of [`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: I tried replacing % with ! in the if statement and it did not work along with SETLOCAL EnabledDelayedExpansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand why not using `"ProjectLoad_Refresh_%today%*.txt"` as wildcard pattern instead of just `*.txt`, but this code should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Today=2017-08-11"
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set "TruncatedName=!FileName:~0,28!"
    if "!TruncatedName!" == "ProjectLoad_Refresh_%Today%" set "FileName=!TruncatedName!"
)
endlocal
```

There is one exception: A file name contains 1 or more exclamation marks.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This works fine. I'll look into the commands, thanks for the suggestions.