# Windows Batch : Wrong behavior when double clicked - Works fine on prompt

Tags: string, batch-file, directory, double-click

THE QUESTION IS EXACTLY THAT I DID THAT AND NOT WORKED

This script is running fine if I go to the prompt and call the file.bat, get all files *.gsc and clean the lines without that string.

But when I double clicked didn't work as expected, and even the first file is deleted everytime I run, and none of the remaining files were cleaned. :\

```
@echo off
set "string_to_find=level.waypoints\["
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B *.gsc') do (
            set "tempfile=%temp%\%%a"
            if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
            findstr /C:"%string_to_find%" "%~dp0\%%a" >> "%tempfile%"
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                        del "%%a" >NUL
                        move /Y "%tempfile%" "%~dp0\%%a" >NUL
                        if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
                        echo File "%~dp0\%%a" processed successfully 
            ) else (
            echo Problem processing file "%~dp0\%%a"
            )
)
```

I already tryed to use

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

And also replace the vars for "!" instead of "%", but I'm doing something wrong... could you help me pointing what I exact I need to change to make this work also with double click?

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch if statement not working in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638465/batch-if-statement-not-working-in-for-loop)

Comment: My questions was exactly saying that I tryed that and did not worked, there's something wrong... not duplicate. Problem persist.

Comment: It is a duplicate because the batch file also does not really work on running it from a command prompt window. On first run of the batch file all occurrences of `%tempfile%` are replaced by nothing before executing __FOR__ command at all. On second run of the batch file in same command prompt window `%tempfile%` is replaced by last value assigned to it from last loop run from previous batch file execution before executing __FOR__ command the first time on second batch file execution because this environment variable still exists from previous batch file execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many hours of tryes I finally get it working with double click now. Here the final code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string_to_find=level.waypoints\["
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B *.gsc') do (
            set "tempfile=!temp!\%%a"
            if exist "!tempfile!" del "!tempfile!" >NUL
            findstr /C:"!string_to_find!" "%~dp0\%%a" >> "!tempfile!"
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                        del "%%a" >NUL
                        move /Y "!tempfile!" "%~dp0\%%a" >NUL
                        if exist "!tempfile!" del "!tempfile!" >NUL
                        echo File "%~dp0\%%a" processed successfully 
            ) else (
            echo Problem processing file "%~dp0\%%a"
            )
)
```

cheers

Comment: Fails with GSC files that contain exclamation marks within their name.

Comment: The point with `delayedexpansion` is that `!var!` is *required* where the value of `var` is changed in a block (typically the body of a `for` loop) and the *new* value of `var` is required. `%var%` will always be replaced by the value of `var` *at the time the* `for` *is  reached*. Hence, since only `tempfile` is being changed in your `for` loop, only `%tempfile%` needed to be changed to `!tempfile!`. As `temp` and `string_to_find` are *not* changed in the loop, they could have remained as `%var%`.

Comment: And `%~dp0\%%a` is better written `%~dp0%%a` because `%~dp0` always expands to drive and path of argument 0 (batch file path) ending with a backslash. The Windows kernel functions for directory and file accesses have no problem with ``\\`` in a directory/file path, but the usage of two successive directory separators within a path should be nevertheless avoided if that is easily possible like here.